# How to add hashmap into Redis?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using Redis in my Spring-data-redis project. I am trying to insert HashMap into Redis, but I cannot find the API for that?

```
public class EmployeeRepositoryImpl {
private static final String KEY = "Employee";

private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;
private HashOperations hashOperations;

@Autowired
public EmployeeRepositoryImpl(RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate){
    this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
}

@PostConstruct
private void init(){
    hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
}

public void add(HashMap<Integer, Employee> employees) {
    hashOperations.put(KEY, employees);
}
```

}

Comment: There's no such api.

Comment: @sazzad Then what should I do? Should I loop the hashmap, and get hashmap key and value and insert into Redis?         hashOperations.put(KEY, 1, new Employee(1, 123));

Comment: "Should I loop the hashmap" - yes. The method is `hSet`, not `put`. Also, you'll need to serialize those arguments.

Comment: @sazzad Thank you. Do you have any recommended API or tutorial can give a overall usage about Redis? Although I can google it online, just want to have a reference

Comment: hashOperations.putAll(KEY, <? extends Map> object);